# How can I replace MORE characters at a particular index in JS?

Tags: javascript, replace

I know how to replace one character at a particular index, but I don't know, how can I replace more characters.

I already tried FOR loop, but it didn't work.

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

var str = "hello world";
var indices = [1, 4, 9];

for(i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    str.replaceAt(indices[i], "?");
}
```

The `str` after loop should be `"h?ll? wor?d"`, but it's `"hello world"`

Comment: Try `str = str.replaceAt....`.

Comment: Strings are immutable in javascript — you can't replace them in place. You need to save the results to a new string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your `replaceAt` method your not changing the passed string (which wouldn't be possible since strings is immutable), your creating a new one, so if you change your for loop to replace the string it will work:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index,replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

var str = "hello world";
var indices = [1, 4, 9];

for(i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    str = str.replaceAt(indices[i], "?");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an assignment for every step of replacement.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

var str = "hello world";
var indices = [1, 4, 9];

for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    str = str.replaceAt(indices[i], "?");
}

console.log(str);
```